# How can i secure communications from Django to a Flask microservice?

Tags: python, flask

I designed a simple Django service which communicates with a Flask microservice using POST Requests.
Basically, the user submits a form with some preferences, those preferences are sent to a Django view, the Django view will send those to Flask, which will perform some operations according to those preferences and then return a response to Django, which will show it to the user or do some other operations.

This whole system works for now, the only problem is that i don't know how safe it is. Here is how i'm sending the request:

```
def myview(request):
    # Some code ... 
    req = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000', json=myDataDict)
```

And here is how my Flask service receives it:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def receivePost():
    data = request.get_json()
    # some code .. 
    return jsonify(data)
```

Again, this system works locally; i want to make it safer for when i'll deploy it.

Here are my concerns:

1) What if a third party reads what's inside the variable `myDataDict` when the two services are communicating?
2) The Flask service should accept requests ONLY from the Django service.

I made some research and found about libraries such as OAuth2, and a token authentication system would be a good way to make this system safer, but i don't really know how to add it to my actual code. So here is my question: how can i make this system safe? Any kind of advice is appreciated.

Comment: So an easy way to avoid myDataDict to be read should be to use an https request. You data is encrypted when sent, so unless you have reason to believe that your server has been hacked you should be fine. Of course if you don't have the right certificates you don't know for 100% who you are talking to. If that is too risky for you, use a key pair. (Look up asymmetric encryption) As long as noone steals your private keys you are good. As far as that only you can make requests there are multiple options. (for example: create an apikey (a secret that has to be sent with a request) or limit by IP)

Comment: If you want to be really secure you should follow a checklist. Have a look at this: https://restfulapi.net/security-essentials/

Comment: The api keys system is a good way to go! Yes, i'm already making sure that the service will use HTTPS requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Flask-login` to authenticate users using an `API` key and `IP` address. Here is an example.

```
@login_manager.request_loader
def load_user_from_request(request):
    api_key = request.headers.get('My-Api-Key')
    is_api_path = re.match(r"^/api/+", request.path)
    if is_api_path and api_key:
        user = User.query.filter_by(key=api_key).first()
        if user and user.ip == request.remote_addr:
            return user

    return None
```

Using `Flask-login`'s `request_loader` to load and authenticate users without using cookies.

First get the `API` key from `HTTP` header called `My-Api-Key` here. Then check that the request `URL` contains `/api/` to narrow where you can authenticate with `API`.

If the user is found check that the request is coming from their `IP`.

Inside your `Django` application you can request `FLASK` application like this.

```
resp = requests.post(url + "/api/myendpoint", json=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'My-Api-Key': api_key})
```

Finally don't forget to use `HTTPS`